# 'Unhandled exception in script' error when opening .py file converted to .exe

Tags: python, error-handling, pyqt5

I'm trying to convert a .py file into an executable, but i've encountered some problems in the process; I first tried the conversion with pyinstaller using the following command

```
pyinstaller -w -F main.py
```

The command runs fine, but when I try to open the .exe it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alessandro\PycharmProjects\Browser\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

To try to solve this I've uninstalled and installed again the two modules i downloaded during the coding process:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

None of this worked, so I tried with another method I've seen recommended here: auto-py-to-exe. It kept giving me the same error, and following a comment under this post I used the option "--hidden-import" giving the program the two modules I wrote above, which resulted in yet another error when trying to open the file

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

Not knowing what to do at this point, I've tried to insert in the "--hidden-import" option also the missing module in the error, which unsurprisingly ended up giving me the same error when opening the .exe

I'll put the code of the program here for further clarificarion:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://nsfwswipe.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()

        #navbar
        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)

        back_btn = QAction('Back', self)
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)

        forw_btn = QAction('Forward', self)
        forw_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forw_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction('Reload', self)
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction('Home', self)
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navbar.addAction(home_btn)

        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_url)

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://search.networkchuck.coffee'))

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        url = self.url_bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))

    def update_url(self, q):
        self.url_bar.setText(q.toString())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('HiddenWeb')
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You probably haven't bundled `PyQTt5` into the exe file.

Comment: can you include images of the py-to-exe GUI options you select? there should be a --hidden-import option for you to include dependencies

Comment: @smcrowley i've found the option and put in it the two dependencies i've installed during the project (PyQt5 and PyQtWebEngine) but still i get this error:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'

Comment: Please [edit] your post and carefully explain what you tried, including the commands you used (as text, ***NOT*** as images).